# nestjs terminus - tons of failed calls to fs.statSync() for simple typeorm healthcheck

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I set up a simple health check in nestjs using terminus.

```
export class ReadinessController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private db: TypeOrmHealthIndicator,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  readiness() {
    return this.health.check([
      async () => this.db.pingCheck('database', { timeout: 3000 }),
    ]);
  }
}
```

In Datadog APM, I see dozens of failed fs.stat() calls for various paths under /dist

[image]

But the health check seems to complete fine after those calls. Any idea why this is happening?